Why i keep geeting this problem when someone tries to register?
When i try and register in my live project in the server i keep getting this error even though the registration process is completed.
 local.ERROR: Expected response code 354 but got code "503", with message "503-All RCPT commands were rejected with this error:
503-No such recipient here
503 Valid RCPT command must precede DATA
" {"exception":"[object] (Swift_TransportException(code: 503): Expected response code 354 but got code \"503\", with message \"503-All RCPT commands were rejected with this error:

503-No such recipient here

503 Valid RCPT command must precede DATA

\" at /home/musalamarket/domains/musala.market/application/vendor/swiftmailer/swiftmailer/lib/classes/Swift/Transport/AbstractSmtpTransport.php:459)
[stacktrace]

My .env
MAIL_DRIVER=sendmail
MAIL_HOST=localhost
MAIL_PORT=587
MAIL_USERNAME=no-reply@musala.market
MAIL_PASSWORD="NEtVfBGALmpNVmKenZ3C"
MAIL_ENCRYPTION=NULL
MAIL_FROM_ADDRESS=no-reply@musala.market
MAIL_FROM_NAME="${APP_NAME}"

My mail.php
    'mailers' => [
        'smtp' => [
            'transport' => 'smtp',
            'host' => env('MAIL_HOST', 'smtp.mailgun.org'),
            'port' => env('MAIL_PORT', 587),
            'encryption' => env('MAIL_ENCRYPTION', 'tls'),
            'username' => env('MAIL_USERNAME'),
            'password' => env('MAIL_PASSWORD'),
            'timeout' => null,
            'auth_mode' => null,
        ],

I have tried to change the email in the server change the password and nothing works, before it was working fine bot now is not working.

No such recipient here means it doesn't like your authentication. Your mail server is locked down with proper authentication, and there is no no-reply user.

I think the issue is how you are handling the MAIL_DRIVER in the .env file.
In the .env file your MAIL_DRIVER=sendmail So please change it to MAIL_DRIVER=smtp
And also please cross check the SMTP credentials once again with some online tool like https://www.gmass.co/smtp-test.
